# Rabbit MQ on RPi WIN10 IoT

Tags: raspberry-pi, rabbitmq, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying to install RabbitMQ on my Visual Studio 2017 project for Raspberry Pi.

I'm trying by 2 differents ways :

```
1) This first : https://paolopatierno.wordpress.com/2015/08/17/windows-iot-core-and-m2mqtt-a-simple-marriage/
    I'm trying to add RabbitMqClient instead of M2Mqtt used in this tutorial.
    I've got this error (in french) :

Install-Package : Le package RabbitMQ.Client 4.1.1 n'est pas compatible avec uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0). Le package RabbitMQ.Client 4.1.1 prend en charge :
- net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
- netstandard1.5 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.5)

But i use .NET 4.5.1 or +. And when I'm trying to add the "RabbitMQ.Client.dll" to my project, I've got the following error :

'A reference to '...' could not be added. The project targets '.NETCore' while the file reference targets '.NETFramework'. This is not a supported scenario.'


2) The second way i'm trying to explore is to create a new "Background Application (IoT)" but i have the same errors.
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, RabbitMQ.Client not supported in UWP because it has some dependencies not supported in UWP. So, you got those error information.

But RabbitMQ.Client supported in .NET Core.

And Windows iot core recently has .NET Core available(**As it currently stands it's not an official release**).

**Attention: Some information relates to pre-released product which may be substantially modified before it’s commercially released. Microsoft makes no warranties, express or implied, with respect to the information provided here.**

So you can run .Net Core app, console app for example, on Windows iot core with RabbitMQ.Client supported. You can do it like this:

1. Create .Net Core console app.
2. Install RabbitMQ.Client for the app using this command:

   `dotnet add package RabbitMQ.Client`
3. [Add the namespace and code lines](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/dotnet/Send/Send.cs).
4. Compile the app into an executable for ARM platform.
5. Copy your app(in the following path) to the Raspberry Pi and execute the .exe.

`[YOUR PROJECT NAME]\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\win8-arm\publish`

For more information you can reference "[Running Native .NET Core Apps on Raspberry Pi (ARM)](https://microsoft.hackster.io/en-US/Ra5tko/running-native-net-core-apps-on-raspberry-pi-arm-0bb717?ref=channel&ref_id=4087_trending___&offset=9)".

Comment: Helo Rita Han,

Thanks a lot for your answer. I have now a .exe with RabbitMQ in a Core Console App project. In this project, i put this code (worker.cs) : 

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html

When i'm lauch it from Powershell connected to my RPi3, the .exe launch, consume one message of my queue if there is messages but stop instantly. Do you have any idea about this problem ? Thx again.

Comment: Have you tried using [Putty](http://www.putty.org/) instead of Powershell?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That works !!! How can you explain that ? :) I have a last question, do you know if it's possible to set this .exe as a service ? If the RPi3 crash or reboot, this .exe must start automatically. Thanks again for your replies.

Comment: You can check ["DotNetCore.WindowsService".](https://github.com/PeterKottas/DotNetCore.WindowsService)